# Нужны ли запятые в этих двух конкретных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, запятые

1) *К тому же одно дело – близость к развитой Германии, и совсем другое – к Прибалтике, промышленное производство которой тоже сворачивается.*
Нужна ли запятая перед «и» в данном случае? Если да/нет, то почему?

2) *Инструмент ОЭЗ используется правильно там, где уже было развитие и его хотели ускорить.*
Нужна ли запятая перед «и» в данном случае? Если да/нет, то почему?
По идее, обе части в придаточном относятся к слову «там», а значит, запятая не нужна. Но есть сомнения. Может, «и его хотели ускорить» по значению относится к «где уже было развитие». Хотя, может, это звучит как бред.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> К тому же одно дело – близость к развитой Германии, и совсем другое – к Прибалтике, промышленное производство которой тоже сворачивается.

Я думаю, *и* здесь играет роль противительного союза (может быть заменено на *а*), поэтому **запятая нужна.**

> Инструмент ОЭЗ используется правильно там, где уже было развитие и его хотели ускорить.

У нас два однородных придаточных, прикрепленные к главному одним союзным словом *где* (во втором придаточном это союзное слово можно легко восстановить). Они  связаны одиночным соединительным союзом *и*. **Запятая не ставится.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!